# Convert non-json string version of object to object

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, system.text.json

How do I convert a string version of an object that is not JSON, to the object type?

I'm creating a custom model binder for this struct so that I can send it as a Query Parameter:

```
[Serializable]
[ModelBinder(BinderType = typeof(DiscriminatorTagsBinder))]
public struct DiscriminatorTags : IDiscriminatorTags
{
    public DiscriminatorTags(List<int> tags, string discriminator, bool selected)
    {
        this.Tags = tags;
        this.Discriminator = discriminator;
        this.Selected = selected;
    }

    [Required]
    public List<int> Tags { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Discriminator { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public bool Selected { get; set; }
}
```

The binder:

```
public class DiscriminatorTagsBinder : IModelBinder
{

    public DiscriminatorTagsBinder()
    {
    }

    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bindingContext));
        }

        var modelName = bindingContext.ModelName;

        // Try to fetch the value of the argument by name
        var valueProviderResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(modelName);

    

        var x = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<DiscriminatorTags>(valueProviderResult.FirstValue);

        if (valueProviderResult == ValueProviderResult.None)
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        bindingContext.ModelState.SetModelValue(modelName, valueProviderResult);

        var value = valueProviderResult.FirstValue;

        // Check if the argument value is null or empty
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(valueProviderResult);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

The value to deserialize is actually not JSON, it is a string version of the object:

> "DiscriminatorTags(tags: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13,
> 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 900], selected: true, discriminator: GroceryItm)"

So I am getting a JsonException when I do this: `var x = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<DiscriminatorTags>(valueProviderResult.FirstValue);`

How do I convert the non-json string to the `DiscriminatorTags` struct type?

Comment: If `valueProviderResult.FirstValue` is not well-formed JSON, you cannot use `JsonSerializer` to deserialize it, or `Utf8JsonReader` to parse it.  In particular `Utf8JsonReader` is a sealed ref struct with no extension points for customizing the token stream grammar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might sound obvious but you're going to have to manually parse your string. There is no free lunch here. Something like this could get you started:

```cs
var str = "DiscriminatorTags(tags: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 900], selected: true, discriminator: GroceryItm)";
var matches = Regex.Matches(str, @"(tags:\s*\[(.*)\])|(selected:\s(true|false))|(discriminator:\s\w*)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
var tagsMatch = matches[0].ValueSpan;
var bracketStartIndex = tagsMatch.IndexOf('[');
var tagsList = tagsMatch.Slice(bracketStartIndex + 1, tagsMatch.LastIndexOf(']') - 1 - bracketStartIndex);
var list = new List<int>();
foreach (var match in Regex.EnumerateMatches(tagsList, "[0-9]+"))
{
    list.Add(Convert.ToInt32(tagsList.Slice(match.Index, match.Length).ToString()));
}
var selectedMatch = matches[1];
var isSelected = Regex.Match(selectedMatch.Value, "true|false", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
var discriminatorMatch = matches[2].ValueSpan;
var discriminator = discriminatorMatch[(discriminatorMatch.IndexOf(':') + 1)..].Trim();
```

You would need to harden it to guard against missing values etc. and also use a compiled instance for the Regex